# Connecting to the database in a Created Library - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have a little issue right now and its bugging me, hopefully one of you guys will be able to help me out.

Basically I'm creating a library to use in CodeIgniter and I'm getting this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Functions::$db

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 11
```

The Database library is already on autoload aswell as my functions library:

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','encrypt','functions');`

The `Functions.php` file is located in the `application/libraries` folder accordingly.

Line number 11 consists of this:

`$this->db->where('username', $data);`

Not sure as to why the `db` is an undefined property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably because you need to get the CI instance first since not everything is loaded yet:

```
$ci =& get_instance();
$ci->db->where('username', $data);
```

See if that helps. Also see the instructions [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html).

Comment: I just literally found that as well, I really should have scrolled down just a little further before posting this question! Thanks.

Comment: By the way, can you explain to me the `&=` i've never seen that before.

Comment: It's called [passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) (instead of by value)... it means here's you're accessing the existing CI object and now creating a copy of it. You might find it interesting to read about [Singleton patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Actually, the `&` is related to the function name, not the `=` operator...